Using Geocentric or Geodedic latitude with Great Circle Distance
I've recently started working on a system does some work using geodetic coordinate systems. The data it uses is WGS84 and some of the modern components use a Vincenty Algorithm for distance but there are legacy components of the system that use Great-circle for distance.
I'm relatively new to Geodesy but my understanding is that the Geodetic systems are all using Geodetic Latitude(ϕ) and Spherical approaches like Great-circle use Geocentric Latitude(ϕ'). Wikipedia defines the following relation between them:
$$tan(\phi') = (1-e^2) tan(ϕ)$$
I can use this to translate between them but a lot of the reading I'm seeing online isn't very explicit about which latitude they are using and when to convert between them.
Is it the case that when I have coordinates with geodetic latitudes that I should translate them to geocentric coordinates before I use them in Great-circle calculations and then back to geodetic coordinates when they're going back into a geodetic context?
